# Caching MVC 3 views fetched from a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, virtualpathprovider

I have a MVC3 application that is serving views stored in a database. I created a `VirtualPathProvider` and in my `GetFile` and `FileExists` methods I go to the database and return the correct thing. So far so good.

Now I want to cache the view I return from `GetFile`. I understand MVC already does some view caching and we have some control with it via `GetCacheDependency` method. But do we have more control than this? For example, can we use a custom cache there? In my case, I'm interested in caching the views on local filesystem and do my own cache invalidation.

An easy way would be to do it myself in my `GetFile` method, but if there's a natural extensibility point for this in MVC I would rather use it instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at something, noticed your question, has not been answered. You would need to override `GetFileHash()` along with `GetCacheDependency()`. Then you would need to implement your own [CacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163955.aspx) to invalidate the ASP.NET Cache.

Comment: You are right parsh, I found that after posting the question and forgot to update it. Although I was under the impression that you could do it by overriding *either* GetFileHash or GetCacheDependency. We did it just with GetCacheDependency.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `OutputCacheAttribute`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx

or try deriving from it.

Comment: I don't think that's the same thing. AFAIK, output cache will cache the result of the rendered view. View cache will cache the raw view contents prior to rendering.